firebase integration export to bigquery error message
We using firebase to collect events, google analytics is enabled in firebase.
Also integration with bigquery is enabled. How can we see error message when something crashes uploading events into bigquery.
We have working proccess of firebase collecting events from app and sending analytics events to google bigquery. Everything worked fine, but one day upload did not happen and we cannot find error message, what caused upload to crash. In googe cloud logging we can see that that one day of 30th of March is missing from logging, and zero message that error happened during upload.
I tried this in cloud logging
severity: "ERROR"
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.insert"
Cannot find appropriate error.
From Logging I can see every day 3 uploads happening: for the previous day, previous day - 1 and previous day - 2, but the log on 31 of March missing 30th
2024-03-31 00:06:50.439000 UTC - "table_id": "events_20240328"
2024-03-31 00:06:50.461000 UTC - "table_id": "events_20240329"
2024-04-01 00:11:32.617000 UTC - "table_id": "events_20240329"
2024-04-01 00:11:33.063000 UTC - "table_id": "events_20240331"
2024-04-01 00:11:33.383000 UTC - "table_id": "events_20240330"
2024-04-02 00:50:19.577000 UTC - "table_id": "events_20240401"
2024-04-02 00:50:19.715000 UTC - "table_id": "events_20240330"
2024-04-02 00:50:19.821000 UTC - "table_id": "events_20240331"
No logs, no errors
Is it possible that the job that had to upload 30th of March data delayed more than 24 hours and just destroyed? Firebase supprot said that it's not their field of experties. I also want to understand whose problem this is analytics or bigquery if it's clearly not firebase's.
p.s intraday had events of 30th of march

If this work is very important, did you make any backups for it? Or, if it was deleted, have you tried data recovery tools for it?

Yes, I did backup, but still want to now what happened

It might be possible that namely during upload the server was down and wasn't sending any error messages. That's why they haven't been logged. Another possibility is that your work could contain something that server can't handle. Is your work already deployed in another day?

Yes, it was deployed before, one day crashed and continued working, one day and can't find why. It's all in cloud. It means that google cloud servers crashed? <

It is the one of the possibilities. Even if downtime was 2-3 minutes, the deploy might fail.
